# How to send Receipts to Xero using calcinai/xero-php - Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, xero-api

I am trying to send a receipt (bill/ expense) as a draft to the Xero, but what ever I try and do, I am getting an error. Basically, I want to upload the receipt( the invoice sent by the supplier), enter the Name of the supplier, Amount to pay, Invoice Number from the supplier and our reference code merged (eg: Inv Num / Ref as 987/ 123), due date, and a small description like 1 dozen blue ball pens.
Can you please guide me how to solve this issue please.

```
$invoice= new \XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Receipt();
$xcontact= new \XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Contact();

$xcontact->setName('Test Contact');
$xcontact->setFirstName('Test');
$xcontact->setLastName('Contact');
$xcontact->setEmailAddress('amo.chohan@gmail.com');
$xcontact->setDefaultCurrency('AUD');
$invoice->setContact($xcontact);

// till the above code, things are working fine but having issues here)

 $invoice->setTotal('300.00');
 $dateInstance = new DateTime();
 $invoice->setDate($dateInstance);
 $invoice->setReceiptNumber('987/');
 $invoice->setReference('123');
```

i was trying to send the info but giving me an error as:

> Call to undefined method XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Receipt::setReceiptNumber()

and if comment the setReceiptNumber(); I get the following error as:

> XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Receipt::$LineItems is mandatory and is
>   either missing or empty.

Not too sure how can I send the Bills to the Xero.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Phil I tried this and i am getting this error **Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx). ()**

Comment: Are you not adding any line items in your invoice?, eg 1 dozen blue ball pens => $2

Comment: Yeah you need at least one line item.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sendEmail()` function to send email.

```
$invoice->sendEmail();
```